# AngularJS Routing problems with view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to create a sigle-page app that contains shop list, in every shop card is the link to another view that contains table with products.

A shop looks like:

```
shop = {
  id: 1,
  name: "foo",
  description: 'bar',
  products: [item1, itemn];
};
```

app.js:

```
angular
  .module('lightpointTestApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.sortable'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .when('/products/:shopID', {
        templateUrl: 'views/products.html',
        controller: 'ProductsCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Main.html view where are shop list:

```
<h3>Shop list</h3>
<div class="row shopsContainer" ui-sortable ng-model="shops">

  <div class="col-lg-3 shopCard" ng-repeat="shop in shops">
    <button class="btn close cardClose" ng-click="removeShop($index)">&times;</button>
    <div class="cardNumber">{{ shops.indexOf(shop) + 1 }}</div>
    <div class="cardHeader">{{ shop.name }}</div>
    <div class="cardBody">
      {{ shop.address }}<br />
      {{ shop.hours }}<br />      
      <a href="/#/products/{{ shop.id }}">View {{ shop.products.length }} products</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" ng-model="newShop.name" placeholder="Shop name" class="col-lg-3" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="newShop.address" placeholder="Shop address" class="col-lg-3" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="newShop.hours" placeholder="Shop hours" class="col-lg-3" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary col-lg-3" type="button" ng-disabled="!newShop.name || !newShop.address || !newShop.hours" ng-click="addShop()">Add Shop</button>
</div>

</span>
</div>
</div>
```

products.js - controller for products page

```
angular.module('lightpointTestApp')
  .controller('ProductsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, shops) {
    $scope.shopList = shops;
    $scope.shop = {};

    $scope.getShop = function (id) {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.shopList.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.shopList[i].id === id) {
          return $scope.shopList[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    };

    var shopID = $routeParams.shopID;
    $scope.shop = $scope.getShop(shopID);

  })
```

products.html where is the table with products

```
<h2>{{ shop.name }}</h2>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in shop.products">
     <td> {{ product.name }} </td>
     <td> {{ product.description }} </td>      
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The problem is that products.html doesn't bind with products.js and show something like {{shop.name}} and an empty table.

P.S. I think that products.js isn't correct, but I tried everything to do it well.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you included the js file in the products.html?

Comment: Yes, it is included in index.html (index contains ng-view where change shops view and products view)

Comment: Are you getting an error in your console?  I don't think ProductsCtrl is going to know what `shops` is.

Comment: Hm...There's error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: shopsProvider <- shops <- ProductsCtrl` It seems you're right. But why this happened?

Comment: I would expect that `shops` will be `null` and you'll get an error while trying to iterate through the $scope.shopList.length in `getShop`

Comment: How should I get shops array? I don't use $http, just define shops in main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a parameter `shops` in `ProductsCtrl`, but there is nothing that will pass a value for it, so it is going to be `null`.  You set the value of `$scope.shopList` to it, and then try to iterate over a NULL array, so you get an exception.

You can store the values of `shops` in a service, and then pass them around your app via injection.  You can initialize their values within main.js, or within the service itself, and then the values will be available if you inject them into `ProductsCtrl`, something like

```
angular.module('lightpointTestApp')
      .controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'shopsService', 
         function ($scope, $routeParams, shopsService) {
             $scope.shopList = shopService;
             $scope.shop = {};

             $scope.getShop = function (id) {

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.shopList.length; i++) {
                  if ($scope.shopList[i].id === id) {
                     return $scope.shopList[i];
                  }
                }
                return null;
             };

            var shopID = $routeParams.shopID;
            $scope.shop = $scope.getShop(shopID);

        }]);
```

shopsService could look something like

```
angular.module('lightpointTestApp')
   .service('shopsService', function() {
       return [ 
                // add whatever fields you need here from code in main.js
                { name: 'shop1', address: 'addr1' },
                { name: 'shop2', address: 'addr2' }
              ];
   });
```

Comment: When I moved initializing data from main.js to shopsService.js, in console appeared `Unknown provider: shopsServiceProvider <- shopsService <- MainCtrl` Why does it happen? `angular.module('lightpointTestApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, shopsService)` - should I declare shopsService anywhere else?

Comment: if you're going to initialize the shopService values in MainCtrl, then you will need to inject it the same way I did for ProductsCtrl, something like `.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'shopsService', function($scope, shopsService) { ...`

Comment: If I remove it, shopsService will be undefined,  as it was to be expected =)

Comment: If I do `.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'shopsService', function($scope, shopsService) { ..` it gives unknown provider.. Uggrrhh

Comment: And you've included the shopsService script file in your index.html (or whatever)?  Can you post a fiddle or plunker or somewhere to reproduce the problem?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/maryja_piaredryj/lightpoint-shops/src - here is the project. Thanks!

Comment: When you inject the dependencies as an array, your main.js is not closing the array after defining the function.  Change line 40 of your main.js to `}]);` and I got the page to start working. The code you have checked in does not have the injection for `shopsService` in `ProductsCtrl`, btw

Answer (score 0):

Where are your shop objects coming from? You are passing in shop, in products.js but not referencing it in the code.  You should also use $q to use promises for async data.  Also use the filter() function rather than a for loop to find the shop by shopId.

Are you hitting an API with shops or storing a local json for now?
With angular, you should separate your data logic manipulation in a factory or service as such:

productService.js

```
angular.module('lightpointTestApp')
  .factory('shopService',function($http, $q){
    var shops = [];
    return {
      getShops: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('<path to product.json or api>').success(function(data){
          shops = data;
          deferred.resolve(data);
        }) 
        return deferred.promise;
      },
      getShopById: function(shopID) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(shops.filter(function(chain){
          return chain.id === shopID;
        })[0]);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    } 
  });
```

product.js

```
angular.module('lightpointTestApp')
 .controller('ProductsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $q,shopService) {
    $scope.shopList = [];
    $scope.shop = {};
    var shopID = $routeParams.shopID;

    shopService.getShops.then(function(shops){
      $scope.shopList = data;    
    })

    $scope.getShopById = function(shopID) {
      shopService.getShopById(shopID).then(function(shop){
      $scope.shop = shop;
     });
    }
  });
```